# Regex for matching directory path depth

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm trying to regex match a specific folder depth of varying path strings using bash scripts.

I want to match two levels down from `packages` eg. `/packages/[any-folder-name]/[any-folder-name]/`.

So for example for `/packages/frontend/react-app/src/index.ts` I want to match `/packages/frontend/react-app/` and store it in an array

```
array=()
string="/packages/frontend/react-app/src/index.ts"

[[ $string =~ packages/.*/.*/ ]] && array+=(${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
```

almost works, but it returns `/packages/frontend/react-app/src/`

I've been going round in circles on this for a few hours now.

Comment: It sounds like you might get some mileage out of `find`. Something like `find /packages -maxdepth 2 -type d`

Comment: @xdhmoore unfortunately `find` cannot match a string and capture part of the string. It is not about finding a directory but extracting specific parts of a path contained in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=()
string="/packages/frontend/react-app/src/index.ts"

[[ $string =~ packages/([^/]+/){2} ]] && array+=("${BASH_REMATCH[0]}")
```

Explanation:

`[^/]+` match any non-empty string that does not contain a `/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo '/packages/frontend/react-app/src/index.ts' | sed 's|^\(/packages/[^/]*/[^/]*/\).*$|\1|'
/packages/frontend/react-app/
```

Explanation:

- use `sed` regex:
- `|^...$|` - match the whole string, anchor at beginning and end
- `^\(...\)` - capture stuff inside parenthesis
- `/packages/` - expect this text
- `[^/]*/` - followed by anything non-slash, followed by a slash
- `[^/]*/` - rinse and repeat
- `.*` - discard anything after the captured text
- `|\1|` - replace matched text with the captured text

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a glob expression would be enough.

```sh
# enable nullglob to get an empty array if there is no match
shopt -s nullglob

array=(/packages/*/*/)
echo ${array[*]}
```